# This JS code conflicts with the target="_blank" attribute. What should I add to make this attribute an exclusion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// I understand nothing in JS and work empathically :-)
// This one has been taken from somewhere. Attempts to improve fail :(
// The speed of one transition (fadeIn or fadeOut).
// Full execution time will be:
// (browser navigation time) + speed * 2;
// You can set this to slow, medium, fast, or number of ms.
var speed = 'slow';

$('html, body').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0 || url.indexOf('http') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                window.location = url;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

What should an option of excluding the `target="_blank"` attribute look like? I understand it's somewhere near the ors (`||`) :-), but what's a perfect syntax for that?

Comment: `if (this.target === '_blank') return;`.

Comment: It does work! Thanks :-)